# mysql is not returning all the rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the query I have:

```
  $sqlw = "SELECT * FROM coverages where user_id='3828' ORDER BY sp_id ASC";
  $resultw = mysql_query($sqlw);    
  $roww    = mysql_fetch_array($resultw);
  while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultw)) {

  echo $roww['sp_id']."<br>";

      }
  echo "TOTAL:".mysql_num_rows($resultw)."<br>";
```

As you can see its very basic
the results show : TOTAL:29 
But when I count the list of the items returned back its only 28. 
I ran the query on phpmyadmin it shows a total of 29 rows, I did count them and they are 29.

I ran different other simple queries and it always does the same thing: one row is missing. This could be trivial maybe I am missing something or maybe its server related? any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why do you have 3828 in quotes? Typically, ID columns are integers, and if you put the id in quotes, MySQL will treat it as a string, and force a type conversion. For integers, it is best practice to not wrap them in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `mysql_fetch_array()` before the loop disposes of a row.

Answer (score 2):

You have a classic off-by-one error.

There is an extra `$roww    = mysql_fetch_array($resultw);` before your loop starts. This means you're throwing away the first row.